# Suddenly I need root permission to access external drives, how to change, and how to prevent?

Tags: permissions, mount, sudo

Whenever I inserted an external drive through USB, the computer would automatically mount this on /media/ , making it accessible to anyone.

From one day to another, without any apparent explanation, I need sudo rights to mount anything. And after mounting, every drive changes its access permissions to root. So for example after I mounted a SD card, now no camera or recorder can access it anymore as it is now protected.

How could this have happened? And how can I reverse this to the standard format, where anything is mounted automatically?

PS: I am looking for answers hopefully not having to modify the fstab file, as this has led to booting errors in the past.

Output of

```
pkaction --action-id org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount --verbose


  description:       Mount a filesystem
  message:           Authentication is required to mount the filesystem
  vendor:            The Udisks Project
  vendor_url:        https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks
  icon:              drive-removable-media
  implicit any:      auth_admin
  implicit inactive: auth_admin
  implicit active:   yes
```

Comment: Maybe some change in policykit? what is the output of `pkaction --action-id org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount --verbose`

Comment: @steeldriver added to the question